# Please name me an easily accessible chilli pepper which is low heat, sweet and aromatic?

Tags: chili-peppers

As the question states.  I'd prefer something which has very little heat if any at all but it should be strongly sweet, aromatic and grassy. I am in the UK so something easy to get: fresh or powdered.

Comment: If you don't want heat, any reason you're asking for a chilli rather than just using bell pepper?

Comment: @Cascabel A low heat chilli maybe have sweeter and more tasteful qualities than a bell pepper? As I see it, people dont pick chillis just for heat but rather the flavours that come with it?

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific in your question. Compared to the Carolina Reaper pepper, a Habanero or Thai Birdseye chilis are not too hot, but are only "not hot" by comparison--they can be quite hot. Personally, I'd consider a Jalapeno to be "very little heat" ... But hotness is very subjective, so a more specific question will make for a better answer. Do you find a Jalapeno spicy?

Comment: Sorry, we don't take list type questions. You have to decide for yourself which chilli you enjoy eating. There are scales online which show a rough level of heat, although they aren't perfect, since you have heat differences even between different chillis of the same plant. So you can take such a scale and simply start tasting the chillis from the lower end.

Answer (score 2):

UK stores do not have much variety of chili powder in the low heat range, however you can get good quality paprika in almost all stores. Paprika is low heat, sweet and aromatic (provided you get decent stuff). Some stores sell Spanish Pimentón, which is good quality paprika. Pimentón comes in dulce (sweet) and picante (spicy) although picante isn't really very spicy.

I have found chipotle powder from specialty stores which is also a good choice, it's basically a smoked Jalapeño. I have found Ancho as well, which is red poblano, neither is particularly spicy.

There's a lot of chili powder on offer in the UK that is in the hot range from Indian, Pakistani and Caribbean influences, so many stores have sections for each cuisine, it's worth having a trawl through there to see what you can find as occasionally you'll see mild chili powders for sale, and they are good value.

Comment: Chipotle is a smoked Jalapeño. Ancho is a red poblano. These days you can get both [& more] in the big supermarkets. The only real problem is they don't tell you much about them on the jars, just the name; so you need to know in advance what the properties of each may be.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Tesujin, I had those mixed up. I see both rarely in supermarkets.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use a lot of a mild chilli, you might be better using a tasty pepper, and adding a little heat in a more controlled way. In the supermarkets I go to, the long thin red and yellow sweet peppers tend to have more flavour than the normal bell peppers, and they're sweeter.

When it comes to adding a little controlled (ideally tasty) heat, either: use a finely chopped not-too-hot chilli (like a  jalapeño, or the unspecified varieties often available) early in cooking; or use hot smoked paprika (assuming you like the smoky flavour and it's suitable - Pimenton de La Vera is widely available and reliable.

I have grown almost heatless chillies, but they're not widely sold, and anyway the heat isn't very reliable - you can end up with a batch that have no heat, or more heat than you expect.

Comment: When you say 'long thin red and yellow sweet peppers' do you not know their name or likely heat profile? I mean are these known for being sweet and low in heat?

Comment: @James they have no heat, but are normally sold as something like "sweet pointed red peppers". They may be Corno de Toro, a variety I've grown, but mine are smaller

Answer (score 0):

Another good choice that's relatively available in the UK is Aleppo pepper.

Marash pepper would also be viable, but I don't know how easily available it is.